# Itemize: Identation is different between first and second line

Tags: beamer, biblatex, itemize

I have this problem where it seems that itemize starts with a blank space, whereas the next line starts without it. Is there a way to have both the first and second line aligned? I am using LyX.

[image]

This is a minimal code with the behaviour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Test} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item Test Test Test asdjakhsdahsdk aklsdjklajsd akljsakljd tehlasdklhasd asdhkadha asdhasdha asdhashdasd  
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It thought it may be a common problem with a straightforward solution. But you are right that I should post also the LateX Code

Comment: A more minimal example that still allows to reproduce the indentation issue is the following: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test Test Test asdjakhsdahsdk aklsdjklajsd akljsakljd tehlasdklhasd
asdhkadha asdhasdha asdhashdasd 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: Probably a bug in `biblatex` ...

Comment: ... but actually a `beamer` bug with `biblatex` (and `authoryear` style).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

`beamer` v3.60 with a fix for this issue was released on 14 Dec. 2020 and is available now in MikTeX and TeX Live. The problem should disappear if you thoroughly update your TeX system.

**The workaround** shown below is no longer needed and **should be removed**.

---

### Old answer

This was a timing issue with `beamer`'s `biblatex` adjustments.

The problem was reported at https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/625 and fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/pull/626.

The fixed `beamer` version (v3.60?) hasn't been released yet, though. If you need a fix now, you can use the following temporary workaround suggested by samcarter in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/625

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
\addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Test} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item Test Test Test asdjakhsdahsdk aklsdjklajsd akljsakljd
  tehlasdklhasd asdhkadha asdhasdha asdhashdasd  
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1061

Comment: Thanks for this workaround and the links.