# Indentation of a broken line in beamer interacts with bib latex style

Tags: beamer, biblatex, indentation

I've created the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a bullet point
\item Here, this is a very very very very very very very very very very extremely long bullet point that basically never ends, because it continues on the second line
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

The second bullet point is so long that it gets continued on the next line, but with less indentation than usual (see picture below). If I remove any one of the options to the biblatex package, the indentation works as it's supposed to work. It doesn't matter if there are any actual citations in the document.

[image: Example shows the second line of the second bullet point to have less indentation than the first line]

Any idea how to fix this?

PS: I'm doing this with MacTeX 2020, and after having updated all packages to their current state, today.

PS2: [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565676/itemize-identation-is-different-between-first-and-second-line) indeed solves it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565676/35864 should help.

Comment: It does, thanks!

Comment: Very good! I voted to close your question as a duplicate, so other people can find the answer more easily.