# Problem with citation style in biblatex and bullet lists beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, itemize

Having updated to TeXLive 2020, I’m experiencing a really strange problem with `biblatex` and `beamer`: As soon as a citation style is specified in the biblatex options, text alignment with e.g. bullet lists, etc. is broken.

Here is minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear, % When a specific style is selected, bullet lists are not aligned
    backend=biber,    
    natbib=true]
{biblatex}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text.
\item This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text.
\item This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text. This is a text.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the biblatex block commented out, \labelwidth is set to 16.425pt, with it active, it's set to -3.05006pt. Why this would be I don't know either (maybe BibLaTeX redefines some indentation parameter for bibliography lists?).

Comment: There was a bug with `beamer`'s `biblatex` patches in v3.59. This issue was resolved in v3.60 released in December 2020. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565676/35864. Make sure your TeX live is fully up to date. Just to be sure I compiled your MWE with a fully updated MikTeX installation: There is no misalignment any more.

Comment: Thanks! Updating beamer resolved the issue.